# No address marked as Primary

Tags: addresses, primary

I need to pull a list of members who has no primary address ticked. Has anyone any idea on how I can do this?

When our data came over from our old membership system it took over the addresses but some are not marked as primary and I am trying to find those ones by pulling a list. Thanks

Thanks,

Eileen

Comment: Eileen - can you please clarify what you mean by "primary address ticked"?  Do you mean, no address at all in Civi, or no address marked as primary?  Theoretically if a contact has at least one address in Civi, it is marked by default as primary.

Comment: Hi Lesley. Apologies I mean no address marked as primary. When our data came over from our old membership system it took over the addresses but some are not marked as primary and I am trying to find those ones by pulling a list. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the additional explanation!  One approach you could try is to use Search Builder (Search > Search Builder) and search for contacts whose primary street address is null but whose street address of your default location type (e.g., Main or Home) is not null.  If that doesn't yield the results you want, then you could search for your other location types as well (e.g., where primary street address is null and (Location Type A street address is not null or Location Type B street address is not null or Location Type C street address is not null)).

Comment: I will that a go Lesley. Thanks for your help. Eileen